# Entity Framework Insert many-to-many database first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, many-to-many, entity-relationship

```
    pessoas objPessoa;
DataTable dtTelefones;
DataTable dtEnderecos;
private void salvar()
{
    using (EarthWorkEntities ctx = new EarthWorkEntities())
    {
        frame2objeto();
        ctx.AddTopessoas(objPessoa);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}


private void frame2objeto()
        {
            using (EarthWorkEntities ctx = new EarthWorkEntities())
            {
                objPessoa = new pessoas();
                //Pessoa
                objPessoa.pes_cpfcnpj = textCpf.Text;
                objPessoa.pes_nome = textNome.Text;
                objPessoa.pes_sexo = cbSexo.SelectedIndex == 0 ? "M" : "F";

                //Cliente
                clientes cliente = new clientes();
                cliente.cli_dt_ultima = DateTime.Now;
                objPessoa.clientes.Add(cliente);
                //Telefones
                foreach (DataRow row in dtTelefones.Rows)
                {
                    telefones objTelefones;
                    objTelefones = new telefones();
                    objTelefones.EntityKey = null;
                    objTelefones.tel_contato = row["Contato"].ToString();
                    objTelefones.tel_ddd = row["DDD"].ToString();
                    objTelefones.tel_numero = row["Numero"].ToString();
                    string tipo = row["Tipo"].ToString();
                    tipos_telefones tipo_telefone = (from t in ctx.tipos_telefones
                                         where t.tptel_descr == tipo
                                         select t).FirstOrDefault<tipos_telefones>();
                    objTelefones.tipos_telefones = tipo_telefone;
                    objPessoa.telefones.Add(objTelefones);
                }
                //Endereço
                foreach (DataRow row in dtEnderecos.Rows)
                {
                    enderecos objEnderecos;
                    objEnderecos = new enderecos();
                    objEnderecos.EntityKey = null;
                    objEnderecos.end_bairro = row["Bairro"].ToString();
                    objEnderecos.end_cep = row["CEP"].ToString();
                    objEnderecos.end_cidade = row["Cidade"].ToString();
                    objEnderecos.end_complemento = row["Complemento"].ToString();
                    objEnderecos.end_logradouro = row["Logradouro"].ToString();
                    objEnderecos.end_numero = row["Numero"].ToString();
                    string tipo = row["Tipo"].ToString();
                    tipos_enderecos tipo_endereco = (from t in ctx.tipos_enderecos
                                         where t.tpend_descr == tipo
                                         select t).FirstOrDefault<tipos_enderecos>();
                    objEnderecos.tipos_enderecos = tipo_endereco;
                    objPessoa.enderecos.Add(objEnderecos);
                }
            }
        }
```

When running the command "AddTopessoas ()" returns the following error: "The EntityKey property can only be set when the current value of the property is null."

Tables:
pessoas >> pessoas_telefones << telefones
pessoas >> pessoas_enderecos << enderecos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't quite understand your code. But I did notice that you are not calling `SaveChanges()` inside `frame2objeto()`, so once you go out of using block, they were discarded.

Even though you DID save changes, when you return from it to your `salvar()`, you wouldn't be seeing any changes since it is a separate context altogether.

Comment: I have not pasted the button event.
At the click of the button that calls the two methods.